# PharData buildFromDirectory останавливается из-за ошибки

Tags: php, tar

Ошибка при создании
`Entry Meschanskiy-FIVE_OÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ ?aUcs28 cannot be created: phar error: invalid path "Meschanskiy-FIVE_OÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ ?aUcs28" contains illegal character`
Как я понимаю это недопустимые для кодировки utf-8 символы, но как избежать при создании tar-архива через buildFromDirectory?

Comment: Версия php у вас какая? Предположительно ее еще в 2014 году поправили, эту ошибку.

Comment: @Visman PHP 5.6.26

Comment: Пришел к выводу что в php это версии PharData багнутая вещь и консольная версия работает в разы быстрее. Решил применять ее. С консоли создается сразу tar.gz без промежуточного tar и нету ограничения по длине имени файлов в 100 символов. Если кто-то решит делать это через php с большими объемами данных и большим количеством файлов крайне не рекомендую.